# How to open iTerm2 version 3 in Forklift

Tags: macos, applescript, iterm2, iterm

I am looking for a solution which can open iTerm2 version 3 as the default terminal. For iTerm2 version 2 there were multiple AppleScripts on the internet which worked well for opening the current Forklift dir in an iTerm tab.

In iTerm3 this no longer works, as the scripting changed slightly. I also don't know any possible way to debug what is wrong, as

1. I cannot run the applescript file in standalone, as it depends on ForkLift variables.
2. I don't see any place where ForkLift would log it's output. In Console at least I didn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

The iTerm support has now been built in and can be selected in the settings.

[image: Forklift Settings]

Comment: iTerm and iTerm2 are different projects. For me, this doesn't work for iTerm2